# Sony Vaio laptop not recovering from hibernate

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, hibernate, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio Laptop, model VGN C2S. It has an Intel Core 2 processor, 3GB of RAM and Windows 7 Ultimate N.

The laptop works perfectly until it is put onto hybernation mode. Upon pressing the power button to resume the laptop, it gets stuck in an endless boot where it displays the Vaio logo, then goes to a black screen for two seconds, then instead of proceeding the the "Starting Windows" screen, it jumps back to the Vaio logo, then the black screen, then the Vaio logo, and so on.

If the hard drive is removed from the laptop and installed in a Sony Vaio VGN C1Z, the laptop does not get stuck in an endless reboot loop, instead displaying the Windows Resume Loader menu. Selecting "Delete restoration data and proceed to system boot menu" allows this laptop to boot into Windows 7 again, where it can then be shut down, and the hard drive replaced in the original laptop, which boots up sucessfully.

Does anyone know a way to either make the laptop successfully resume from hibernation, or show the Windows Resume Loader menu so I can boot back into Windows without swapping hard drives and using another laptop?

Thank you

Comment: [Disable hibernation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/920730), reboot, test your drive (using something like `chkdsk /r`) then re-enable hibernation and see if there's any difference.